# Purpose of a capacitor between op amp input and output

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, current-source

what is the purpose of using a 1 uf capacitor between input and output of this op amp?

this is a current source circuit .

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is to stabilize the 120mA current **sink** (the function of this circuit block). The 10K resistor (which is too high, IMO) R13 introduces a pole in the feedback loop, reducing the phase margin, in conjuction with the gate capacitance.

The 1uF and R17 provide a faster AC feedback that negates that, at the expense of rather sluggish response, particularly so because of the values chosen.

You could decrease R13 to something like 100 ohms and C12 to 10nF or even 1nF, probably, with improved AC performance.

---

As to how it works, the R11/R14 voltage divider from +5 yields 238mV at the non-inverting input to the op-amp and the op-amp drives the MOSFET gate to match that voltage at the inverting input, which requires 120mA to flow through the source in order to drop 238mV across the 2 ohm resistor R19.

The simple way to look at it would be to eliminate C12 (open) and R13/R17 (short) and it looks like it might work, but it would probably oscillate or oscillate conditionally.

Comment: i don't get what you mean by "which is too high, IMO". why it is high and what IMO stands for?

Comment: "Too high" means "higher than the ideal value". For example, 1 kohm or 100 ohms might work better than 10 kohms. Even just a few ohms is fairly common in this situation. "IMO" means "in my opinion".

Comment: Sorry for the short form, Photon has it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is an integrator. It makes the output move slowly up or down so the inputs would be equal. All in all the circuit is a "current loop", to understand it you need more theory than just about the capacitor.

Comment: i know that it's a current source with a closed loop feed back.

Comment: Ok. So the controller is I, or integrator.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, there's a second feedback path so that it isn't a pure integrator.

Comment: OK... Anyhow someone had plenty of time to write a whole essay, so it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @The Photon ,where is the second feedback path? i just see one main path

Comment: @alireza, through R17.

Comment: @The Photon , i considered the main path the one through R17. so if you think the path through R17 is second path what is the main path?

Comment: The one that Greg referred to (that has integrating properties) is the one through C12. So in that context, the path through R17 is the "other" path.

Comment: It does feel like in fact this is the same path. It is int{0,t}([Vref - I * Rsense] * [1sC] / Rf). So it's like an error integrator.

Comment: hum, that's an other sight of view, but i think in control theory scientific resources they just consider it as a single feed back loop